# How to pass JSON response from Controller back to AJAX success method in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a calling js script

```
setInterval(function(){

    $.get( "/fetch-data", function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
    });

},1000);
```

and my Routes look like this

```
Route::get('/fetch-data', 'PageController@fetchData');
```

my controller method

```
public function fetchData()
{
    $results_array = [];
    $file = new \SplFileObject('file.csv');
    $file->setFlags(\SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

    foreach ($file as $row) {
        $results_array[] = $row[0];
        $results_array[] = $row[1];
        $results_array[] = $row[2];
        $results_array[] = $row[3];
         ...
    }
     return response()->json($results_array);
     //$json = response()->json($results_array);
     //return view('view.blade',compact($json));    
}
```

Note that with `return response()->json($results_array);` the raw json text is displayed directly on the page. Not what I want.

While `return view('view.blade',compact($json));` returns the whole html file. Still not what I want.

What I would like to achieve is that the raw json text that was returned from the controller be pass to the callback from the calling js script.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the console.log print? Isn't it a JSON string?

Comment: With your code nothing should be displayed directly on the page, the information that is outputted by the php script is stored in the `data` variable. If you see things on your page, something else is going on somewhere else.

Comment: with `return response()->json($results_array);` the raw json string is displayed on the `fetch-data` URI and nothing is displayed on the console log.

Answer (score 0):

The code works as expected.

```
setInterval(function(){

$.get( "/fetch-data", function( data ) {        
 // code now works
});

},1000);
```

and this question was [answered HERE already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42394314/how-to-do-ajax-with-setinterval-in-laravel-5-4).